# kivy: press button -> change color of a label

Tags: python, canvas, colors, label, kivy

in the kv File I added a Label and changed its color:

```
Label:
    id: ampel_rot
    canvas.before:
    Color:
        rgba: 1, 0, 0, 0.3
    Ellipse:
        size: self.size
```

My aim is to create some kind of a traffic light, so that the user of the GUI has some kind of visual feedback over a process.
To do so, I have to change the color of this Label during runtime. 
But however in this case I dont understand the connection between the kv file and the main.py.

I tried something like:

```
self.ids.ampel_rot.canvas.before.Color.rgba(1, 0, 0, 1)
```

Which of course doesnt work.

So how do I change the Labels Color in the main.py? Can somebody enlighten me, please? Thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way is to use an intermediary property

```
from kivy.properties import ListProperty
class ColourLabel(Label):
    ellipse_colour = ListProperty([1, 0, 0, 1])
```

Then in the kv

```
<ColourLabel>:
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgba: self.ellipse_colour
        Ellipse:
            size: self.size
            pos: self.pos
```

Note that I added the pos to Ellipse, which is presumably necessary in general.

You could then add a ColourLabel to the same rule that your original example was in, and the modification code becomes `self.ids.ampel_rot.ellipse_colour = (1, 1, 1, 1)` etc.